# How can I search contacts removed from a specific group?

Tags: custom-search, searchkit

I need to find contacts that have been removed from a specific group to add them back again in. I can find using custom search if they're *not* in a group, but not if they *were* in a specific group.

Is there a way to find them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I authored Subscription History Report and it's a good choice, but these days I would use Search Kit (an extension which ships with CiviCRM - **Administer menu » System Settings » Extensions**.

From there, you can use this (change the domain name):

```
https://example.org/civicrm/admin/search#/create/Contact?params=%7B%22version%22:4,%22select%22:%5B%22id%22,%22display_name%22,%22Contact_GroupContact_Group_01.title%22%5D,%22orderBy%22:%7B%7D,%22where%22:%5B%5B%22Contact_GroupContact_Group_01.title%22,%22%3D%22,%22Newsletter%20Subscribers%22%5D%5D,%22groupBy%22:%5B%5D,%22join%22:%5B%5B%22Group%20AS%20Contact_GroupContact_Group_01%22,%22INNER%22,%22GroupContact%22,%5B%22id%22,%22%3D%22,%22Contact_GroupContact_Group_01.contact_id%22%5D,%5B%22Contact_GroupContact_Group_01.status:name%22,%22%3D%22,%22%5C%22Removed%5C%22%22%5D%5D%5D,%22having%22:%5B%5D%7D
```

If you'd prefer to do it yourself, here's a screenshot of the same search:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Jon G. Once again SearchKit is the solution. Tremendous tool :-)

Answer (score 3):

How about using [Subscription History Report](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/org.cpehn.subscriptionhistory)

Comment: thanks Pradeep. I hadn't heard of this extension. We'll give a try.